# JUnit without inversion of control

Tags: java, junit, junit5

Currently the JUnit5 Framework works with Inversion of Control. I.e. you annotate a test method with `@Test` and then JUnit scans your classpath (in the simplest case)

Now is there a way for me to be in charge of calling the test cases through JUnit APIs? Maybe by hooking my test implementations to some test registry provided by JUnit? 

**I'm pretty new to JUnit** - how did older versions go about this?

The reason I'm asking is that normally to execute my test cases, I'd have to run something along the lines of

```
java -jar junit-platform-standalone.jar --class-path target --scan-class-path
```

on the command line. My situation requires me to run the test cases through by executing one of my own classes, like that e.g.

```
java /com/example/MyTestCassesLauncher
```

**EDIT**: to clarify, I need one of my own classes to be hosting/launching my test cases, something like this:

```
// Maybe this needs to extend one of JUnit's launchers? 
public class MyTestCassesLauncher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JUnitLauncher.launchTests(new MyTestClass());
    }
}
```

where `JUnitLauncher.launchTests` is some kind of API provided by the platform. I'm not looking for a method with that exact same signature but a mechanism that would allow me to ultimately call my own `MyTestClassesLauncher` class to run the tests.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/master/junit-platform-launcher/src/main/java/org/junit/platform/launcher/core/DefaultLauncher.java. But it requires some effort and understanding to use it correctly.

Comment: thanks. that seems to be a possible solution ... Have you ever implemented your own Default Launcher subclass?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you arę actually trying to achieve but in Junit5 to change behaviour of your tests you can use [Extensions](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-extensions) mechanism, similar to Junit4 `RunWith` but more powerful

Such custom extension can provide some additional logic like in this logging example

```
public class LoggingExtension implements 
TestInstancePostProcessor {
    @Override
    public void postProcessTestInstance(Object testInstance, 
      ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(testInstance.getClass());
        testInstance.getClass()
          .getMethod("setLogger", Logger.class)
          .invoke(testInstance, logger);
    }
}
```

The way Junit controls it's flow is Junit problem - you should not modify framework but extend it